# Poor Neo4j performance on enterprise edition

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to switch to the enterprise edition of Neo4j to improve query time for my team's massive graph database (it has 1B relationships). On the interpreted setup, a sample length two expand query was:

```
Available after 10670 ms, consumed after 0ms
```

But running on the compiled edition, the same query was:

```
Available after 6ms, consumed after 6198ms
```

For context, our current pseudo-graph in MySQL achieves speeds under a second. I'm wondering why the compiled edition's consumption is so much slower. Our Neo4j database is stored completely in memory, so that should only favor the enterprise edition.

If it helps... we're also running into a problem where the number of page cache hits per one database hit exceeds 1x10^7. I think these problems are related.

The basic query is:

```
Profile
Match (:Entity {eid:######})-->()<-[:ET##]-(e:Entity)
RETURN e.eid, Count(e)
```

The following is a link to the profile for an interpreted query: [Interpreted Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JFrc.png)

The following is a link to the profile for a compiled query: [Compiled Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSc7Y.png)

Comment: Are you sure to have the same result between those two queries ? I'm asking that because the consumed time is really different (0 to 6198ms). On the second query the execution time is only 6ms, and your browser took 6192ms to retrieve and parse the query data.

Comment: Yes, the query results are the same. Both databases utilize the exact same schema as well.

Comment: Would you be able to provide the PROFILE plans for both queries, with all elements expanded? Even if you're not able to share, look for differences between these, and make sure indexes are being used where expected. If you see that there's a difference in the runtime, you can [force the runtime](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-options/index.html#cypher-runtime) in your query to see if that makes the difference.

Comment: Can you provide the full query?

Comment: If `eid` is unique for :Entity nodes, it would make more sense to perform your count on the node itself and delay property access until after the aggregation (fewer redundant operations): `WITH e, count(e) as freq RETURN e.eid, freq`

Comment: It does reduced the latency by a second or two, but it's still taking way too long compared with our design requirements. Also, the pagecache hits per database hit is still at a magnitude of 10^7.